# Accidental drywall mud over cement board

Tags: drywall, cement-board, drywall-mud

I have a wall in my kitchen being built that will have some drywall and some tile. A dude I hired to finish my drywall, while I wasn't supervising him, applied some drywall mud over the cementboard. I was wondering if that will hinder the adhesiveness of thinset when installing tiles.

[image]

Is it fine as is or should I sand the mud off or, worse yet, have to replace the cementboard?

Answer (score 3):

Thinset is approved for use over sheetrock - sheetrock typically has drywall compound on it.

If you were using a large format tile with a specific thinset that wasn't approved for use over sheetrock you might have issues.

Comment: +1 on it not being an issue, but I would prime the mud to "toughen" the surface a bit more, if not go all the way with finish paint to the edge of the tile so when grouting the wall can withstand all the wiping needed..